# In Linux, are there any functions similar to CreateConsoleScreenBuffer/ReadConsoleOutput to read the terminal contents?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

That is, how to create a new screen buffer and read/ write buffer contents in Linux? The screen buffer I am talking about refers to the content displayed to the user. Or the entire screen.

I don't want to use ncurses. I found terminfo, but I want a function instead of an command. Perhaps ioctl can read the buffer, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking for but [dup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dup) could be used to re-direct stdout/stdin etc. Or maybe you are just looking for `open`/`read`?

Comment: @Lundin I may not make it clear, the screen buffer I am talking about refers to the content displayed to the user. Or the entire screen

Comment: Hmm well I'm guessing you want the APIs that ncurses are built upon then. Linux isn't my forte so I can unfortunately not help much there.

Comment: You want to do what NCurses is explicitly written to do, but you do not want to use NCurses?

Comment: @Dúthomhas emm, Yes, but I think ncurses is displayed by moving to a different position and then writing characters (because on my computer, if a lot of content needs to be displayed, it seems to be refreshed line by line)

Comment: Yes, NCurses only writes _changes_ to the display (so that it doesn’t spend time sending an entire display’s worth of data every time you refresh).

Comment: This is the problem when a Windows programmer attempts to use their knowledge base in other operating systems, rather than *learn to develop on those other operating systems*.  They refuse to use the dedicated interfaces (ncurses, which is actually portable even to Windows), and instead want to use the Windows paradigms they know as-is, everywhere.  Unfortunately, that is not going to work, because each OS has their own approach.  (Well, POSIXy ones like Linux and *BSDs do share the POSIX approach. So maybe it is just Windows versus POSIX, but still.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No

It is given that the *user program* will maintain a buffer of all screen content it wishes to preserve.

This is actually how **NCurses** works: All output functions actually modify the `WINDOW` buffer, and `wrefresh()` causes that buffer to be flushed to the display, as needed.

The Microsoft roadmap for the Windows Terminal expects future TUI programs to do the same, since that is how it works in Linux, I guess.